# How to execute a command on multiple files and redirct output to a different file depending on the name of the input file

Tags: bash, scripts

I am trying to convert a batch of latex files using catdvi.

The command I use for a single file is:

```
catdvi -e 1 -U 1.dvi | sed -re "s/\[U\+2022\]/*/g" | sed -re "s/([^^[:space:]])\s+/\1 /g" > 1.txt
```

However, I want to run the same command on all files from 1.dvi to 30.dvi. When I did:

```
for f in *.dvi ; do catdvi -e 1 -U $f | sed -re "s/\[U\+2022\]/*/g" | sed -re "s/([^^[:space:]])\s+/\1 /g" > "${f%.dvi}.txt"; done;
```

It gives an error expecting 0 or 1 arguments, got 10, etc.

What change do I need to do to the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to a similar question will apply to here also. So, here is the link:

[Batch command that requires output redirection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165828/batch-command-that-reqiures-output-redirection)