# Batch command that reqiures output redirection

Tags: bash, scripts

When I want to process a bunch of tex files, I use

```
for f in *.tex; do latex "$f" ; done;
```

What do I do when I need to redirect output to another file, like in case of catdvi?

The following does not work:

```
for f in *.dvi ; do catdvi -e 1 -U $f  > "${f%.dvi}.txt"; done;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to quote `$f`, so the filename probably got wordsplit due to whitespace in the filename. I also suggest using `./*.dvi` as this avoid problems if a filename starts with a `-` (which will make most commands treat it as a set of options instead of a filename)

```
for f in ./*.dvi; do catdvi -e 1 -U "$f" > "${f%.dvi}.txt"; done
```

Or perhaps combine the two loops

```
for f in ./*.tex; do 
    base=${f%.tex};
    latex "$f" &&
    catdvi -e 1 -U "$base.dvi" > "$base.txt";
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Test it by reducing the complexity of the command. Try this first:

`for f in *.dvi ; do catdvi -e 1 -U $f >> catdvi.txt; done;`

If that works, then the problem is with your dynamic file-name-creation code. Perhaps this would work:

`for f in *.dvi ; do catdvi -e 1 -U $f  > "${f%.dvi.txt}"; done;`

What is the f% trying to do? Should that be $f instead?

`for f in *.dvi ; do catdvi -e 1 -U $f  > "${$f.dvi.txt}"; done;`

Comment: None of the commands work!

On the first and second command, the error is: Expecting zero one 1 arguments. Got 9, etc.

On the third command, the error is Bad substitution.

Hey, I thought this would be simple to do. It is turning out to be quite complex!